# Placing a gradient color on a single dataset (point) of a PCA

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I made a PCA but I need to put a gradient color on only one dataset. I would like to put a color gradient only in the "Campo" variable related to a column of numeric variables (T). I've tried some functions but I still can't do it. Can anybody help me? I really appreciate it. Thanks

I have tried this:

```
df <- jussara[,5:10] 
pca_res <- prcomp(df, scale. = TRUE)

a <- autoplot(pca_res, data = jussara, colour = "matriz", shape = "origem", size = 3,  loadings = TRUE, loadings.colour = 'black',
              loadings.label = TRUE, loadings.label.size = 4)
a
ab <- a + scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2") +
  theme_classic()
ab
```

[current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaIoi.jpg)

and this:

```
a <- autoplot(pca_res, data = jussara, colour = "T", shape = "origem", size = 3,  loadings = TRUE, loadings.colour = 'black',
              loadings.label = TRUE, loadings.label.size = 4)
a
ab <- a + scale_fill_manual(name = "origem", values=c("red","grey50")) +
  theme_classic()
ab
```

[ohter chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCC8d.png)

Comment: Can you please share code to create data? `df <- jussara[,5:10] ` doesn't provide any thing on my side. Also, the libraries you're using to create `prcomp`, `autoplot`

Comment: library(factoextra)
library(ggfortify)

Comment: @DeathMetal  my data is too long, so i just put a part! thanks

>dput(df[1:7, ])
structure(list(T = c(7.35, 7.72, 9.38, 8.12, 8.89, 9.34, 9.87
), LT = c(0.22, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.2, 0.17), FCI = c(26.87, 
21.55, 22.07, 21.77, 19.9, 19.83, 25.6), LTO = c(0.32, 0.34, 
0.45, 0.44, 0.35, 0.41, 0.44), LA = c(26.62, 38.57, 45.23, 27.83, 
39.26, 36.91, 40.65), LMA = c(89.39638658, 58.08224861, 65.2236397, 
80.14375562, 58.83851248, 72.34203967, 45.75308095), LVD = c(0.1167, 
0.1067, 0.1134, 0.1045, 0.1023, 0.1156, 0.1078)), row.names = c(NA, 
7L), class = "data.frame")